# Simple output issue

Tags: java, formatting, output

So in my class we're making simple programs and we're introducing inheritance.  I've gotten everything to work properly, but I can't get this one bit of output to work correctly.  It's when I'm asking for an input, but it skips one of my inputs and goes to the request for the second one.  When I comment all the other things before that aren't needed, it doesn't skip the first input.  I don't understand why this is, and if someone could help me decipher why it would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance and here are my two classes followed by the tester:

Person class:

```
    public class Person{
    private String name, address, phoneNumber;
    public Person(){
        name="none";
        address="none";
        phoneNumber="none";
    }
    public Person(String inName, String inAddress, String inPhoneNumber){
        name=inName;
        address=inAddress;
        phoneNumber=inPhoneNumber;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        name = newName;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String newAddress){
        address = newAddress;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber){
        phoneNumber = newPhoneNumber;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNumber);
    }
    public void clearPerson(){
        name="none";
        address="none";
        phoneNumber="none";
    }
}
```

Customer class:

```
    public class Customer extends Person{
    private int customerNumber;
    private boolean mailingList;
    public Customer(){
        customerNumber=0;
        mailingList=false;
    }
    public Customer(int inCustomerNumber, boolean inMailingList){
        customerNumber=inCustomerNumber;
        mailingList=inMailingList;
    }
    public int getCustomerNumber(){
        return customerNumber;
    }
    public void setCustomerNumber(int newCustomerNumber){
        customerNumber=newCustomerNumber;
    }
    public boolean getMailingList(){
        return mailingList;
    }
    public void setMailingList(boolean newMailingList){
        mailingList=newMailingList;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Customer Number: "+customerNumber+"\nMailing List: "+mailingList+"\n";
    }
    public void clearCustomer(){
        customerNumber=0;
        mailingList=false;
    }
}
```

Tester class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CustomerPersonTester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person testP1 = new Person();
        Customer testC1 = new Customer();
        System.out.println("Empty paramaters constructed on Person and Customer. Results: ");
        System.out.println(testP1.toString());
        System.out.println(testC1.toString());
        /*System.out.println(testP1.getName());
        System.out.println(testP1.getAddress());
        System.out.println(testP1.getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println(testC1.getCustomerNumber());
        System.out.println(testC1.getMailingList());*/
        System.out.println("Expected: none x3, 0, false.\n");
        System.out.print("Enter a new name: ");
        String newName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a new address: ");
        String newAddress = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a new phone number: ");
        String newPhoneNumber = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a new customer number: ");
        int newCustomerNumber = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a new true/false for mailing list: ");
        boolean newMailingList = in.nextBoolean();
        testP1.setName(newName);
        testP1.setAddress(newAddress);
        testP1.setPhoneNumber(newPhoneNumber);
        testC1.setCustomerNumber(newCustomerNumber);
        testC1.setMailingList(newMailingList);
        System.out.println(testP1.toString());
        System.out.println(testC1.toString());
        /*System.out.println(testP1.getName());
        System.out.println(testP1.getAddress());
        System.out.println(testP1.getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println(testC1.getCustomerNumber());
        System.out.println(testC1.getMailingList());*/
        System.out.println("Expected: given name/address/phone number/customer number/boolean.\n");
        testP1.clearPerson();
        testC1.clearCustomer();
        System.out.println("\nTest 1 Complete. Values are reset. Please continue.\n");
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        String inName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter an address: ");
        String inAddress = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a phone number: ");
        String inPhoneNumber = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a customer number: ");
        int inCustomerNumber = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter true/false for mailing list: ");
        boolean inMailingList = in.nextBoolean();
        Person testP2 = new Person(inName, inAddress, inPhoneNumber);
        Customer testC2 = new Customer(inCustomerNumber, inMailingList);
        System.out.println(testP2.toString());
        System.out.println(testC2.toString());
        /*System.out.println(testP2.getName());
        System.out.println(testP2.getAddress());
        System.out.println(testP2.getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println(testC2.getCustomerNumber());
        System.out.println(testC2.getMailingList());*/
        System.out.println("Expected: given name/address/phone number/customer number/boolean.\n");
        System.out.println("Program complete. Terminating...");
        in.close();
    }
}
```

My output keeps looking like this:

```
Empty paramaters constructed on Person and Customer. Results: 
Name: none
Address: none
Phone Number: none
Customer Number: 0
Mailing List: false

Expected: none x3, 0, false.

Enter a new name: Bob
Enter a new address: 123 Happy Lane
Enter a new phone number: 123-456-7890
Enter a new customer number: 12
Enter a new true/false for mailing list: true
Name: Bob
Address: 123 Happy Lane
Phone Number: 123-456-7890
Customer Number: 12
Mailing List: true

Expected: given name/address/phone number/customer number/boolean.


Test 1 Complete. Values are reset. Please continue.

Enter a name: Enter an address: Problem starts here...
```

Comment: This is when you want to learn about debugging. Start with some simple print statements to get a feel for the flow of your code. If that isn't enough, step through it using a debugger. I'd start with narrowing it down though.

Comment: When I comment everything from lines 6-41, it outputs perfectly fine and lets my input for name on testP2. If not, it skips the input for name on testP2. Also, we didn't really learn anything about debugging, so I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: I tried the prints but as JonK pointed out, it's my nextBoolean/nextInt that was messing it up.  That, unfortunately, I can't really see how I would have gotten it with prints, but nonetheless thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You find such a problem by printing the value of your variables. It can indeed be tough to spot, but the method I mentioned is definitely applicable :p Though, I'm glad JonK spotted the scanning error cause as you say, it's not easy to see what's going on there.

Comment: For practice, I'll try to see if I can get a print where I spot my error. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Remember to keep _expected_ values in mind :) Personally, I debug all my programs using prints (instead of a flashy debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `nextBoolean()` *doesn't* consume the newline character that follows either your `true` or `false` input. As a result, this newline character is still in the input buffer when you next call `nextLine()`, which immedately consumes the leftover newline character and then moves on.

To get the expected behaviour, simply add another call to `nextLine()` just after you call `nextBoolean()`. You should also note that this would have happened if `nextInt()` was the last call in the sequence too.

You might also want to think about putting parts of that code into some form of loop (a `while` loop perhaps?) so that you've not got a huge section of duplicated code.

Comment: Thanks for finding that for me.  I didn't know about the non-consumption of the newline character.  Now that I put it the newline for it to consume, I'm home free.  As for the loop, now that I look back at it, I did type out a heck of a lot more than I needed, but I'll keep it in mind for my next tester.  No sense in rewriting what's already overly written lol (in this case only, otherwise, it's actually a good idea to do).